# How to Center Row inside Container ? - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I tried to add [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) ,but it didn't work with me . the BorderSide line centered with me but the **Text** didn't. I think the problem with Container is there any replacement can I use with  the same features .Thanks in advance for your solution .

```
class MenuListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData? icon;
  final String title;
  final Function() onTap;

  const MenuListItem({
    Key? key,
     this.icon,

    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        //width: size.width,
        //alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.black12,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(this.icon),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I called MenuListItem in another class . The structure of the code below .

```
class TestCenter extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestCenter({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Column(
                // here **MenuListItem** widget 
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What ui you like to archive, can you share an image that you like to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the layout you are trying to archive.

[image]

For this we have to use Row `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` and enabling the width of container.
also, you are using `Expanded` on `Text` that need to be removed.

**Widget**

```
class MenuListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData? icon;
  final String title;
  final Function() onTap;

  const MenuListItem({
    Key? key,
    this.icon,
    required this.title,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        width: size.width,
        //alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.black12,
              width: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(this.icon),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you wanted something else.

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
```

to your `Row()` should do the trick